# check PESEL is of 11 digits only - ORA-04073: column list not valid

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

I need a trigger which checks PESEL is of 11 digits only (no letters or other signs).
Please help me correct my code, I receive "ORA-04073: column list not valid for this trigger type"

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER Spr_PESEL
BEFORE INSERT OF PESEL
ON OSOBA
FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE 
v_num NUMBER;
BEGIN
  v_num := (SELECT is_number(:NEW.PESEL) FROM dual);
  IF v_num =0 OR LENGTH(:NEW.PESEL)<> 11 THEN
    Raise_application_error(-20201,'PESEL=' ||:NEW.PESEL|| ' is not of 11 digits');
  END IF;
END; 
/
```

Comment: At which line does the error happen? (Oracle should provide this information together with the error message).

Comment: no line indicator: <br>Error report -<br>
ORA-04073: column list not valid for this trigger type<br>
04073. 00000 -  "column list not valid for this trigger type"<br>
*Cause:    A column list was specified for a non-update trigger type.<br>
*Action:   Remove the column list.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a simple check constraint instead of the trigger:

```
SQL> CREATE TABLE Osoba(
  2    PESEL varchar2(11),
  3    CONSTRAINT PESEL_MUST_HAVE_11_DIGITS
  4    CHECK( length( PESEL ) = 11
  5           and length( trim( translate( pesel, '0123456789', ' ' ))) = 0 )
  6  );

Table created.

SQL> INSERT INTO osoba VALUES( '01234567890' );

1 row created.

SQL> INSERT INTO osoba VALUES( 'A1234567890' );
INSERT INTO osoba VALUES( 'A1234567890' )
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-02290: check constraint (TEST.PESEL_MUST_HAVE_11_DIGITS) violated

SQL> INSERT INTO osoba VALUES( '127890' );
INSERT INTO osoba VALUES( '127890' )
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-02290: check constraint (TEST.PESEL_MUST_HAVE_11_DIGITS) violated

SQL> select * from osoba;

PESEL
-----------
01234567890

SQL> update osoba set pesel = '01234abcdef';
update osoba set pesel = '01234abcdef'
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-02290: check constraint (TEST.PESEL_MUST_HAVE_11_DIGITS) violated
```